# Powershell month name to number

Tags: powershell, date

I have this snippet of code that converts a registry value to a date string (originally hex value 2f 04 1e 00 00 00 00 00):

```
   ElseIf (($sepmastersvc)) {
    $sepmasterst = [bool]$sepmaster
    $sepStatus = $sepmastersvc.status
    $SEPVscan = (get-itemproperty "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\AV") 2> $null
    If (!($SEPVscan)) {
        $SEPVscanStatus = [bool]$SEPVscan
        $SEPDatVer = "N/A"
    }
    Else {
        $SEPVscanStatus = [bool]$SEPVscan
        $SEPDatVerY = [string]($SEPVscan.PatternFileDate[0] + 1970) 
        $SEPDatVerM = ($DateTimeFormat.MonthNames[$SEPVscan.PatternFileDate[1]]) 
        $SEPDatD = [string]$SEPVscan.PatternFileDate[2]
        $SEPDatVer = $SEPDatVerY + $SEPDatVerM + $SEPDatD
    }
}
```

I need to get the month number instead of name.

I've found examples of converting a month number to name but can't get it working the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Get-Date and specify the format. "MM" will retrieve the month in 2 digit number.

```
get-date -format "MM"
```

Here is a list of possible formats: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx

I'm not sure what format your date is, but from what I can see, you could try

```
Get-Date -Date "$SEPDatVerM $SEPDatD $SEPDatVerY" -format "yyyy MM dd"
```

and that should give you a date formatted as this: for example `"2015 03 21"`